# Rogue Weapons Spiked Chain

Tags: dnd-4e

I have been designing a rogue character and it is my understanding that a rogue character is able to use light blades. Therefore I took Spiked chain training which specifies that both ends of the chain would be considered light blades. However the character builder would not accept this. I need to know if my logic is flawed or if there are other feats I need to take to make this work.

Comment: it simply will not allow me equip the chain and I do not have another multi-class feat

Comment: For more accurate debugging, please paste your character into your answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Spiked Chain Training is different from Weapon Proficiency (Spiked Chain).**

Note that, in its default [state](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=3502), a spiked chain is a superior weapon that belongs to the flail group.

Only through taking spiked chain training does it also become a light blade. Therefore, in order to effectively use a spiked chain as light blade as thief, you must have spiked chain training. This feat counts as a multiclass feat. If you have the wrong feat, you may equip the chain but not have it be usable by certain powers, thereby having them appear "blank."

A valid and tested build would be:

```
====== Created Using Wizards of the Coast D&D Character Builder ======
level 1
Human, Rogue
Rogue Tactics: Brutal Scoundrel
Rogue: Rogue Weapon Talent

FINAL ABILITY SCORES
Str 14, Con 10, Dex 20, Int 10, Wis 10, Cha 9.

STARTING ABILITY SCORES
Str 14, Con 10, Dex 18, Int 10, Wis 10, Cha 9.


AC: 17 Fort: 13 Reflex: 18 Will: 11
HP: 22 Surges: 6 Surge Value: 5

TRAINED SKILLS
Stealth +10, Thievery +10

UNTRAINED SKILLS
Acrobatics +5, Arcana, Bluff -1, Diplomacy -1, Dungeoneering, Endurance, Heal, History, Insight, Intimidate -1, Nature, Perception, Religion, Streetwise -1, Athletics +2

FEATS
Human: Spiked Chain Training
Level 1: Light Blade Expertise

POWERS
Rogue at-will 1: Riposte Strike
Rogue at-will 1: Piercing Strike
Rogue encounter 1: Sly Lunge
Rogue daily 1: Checking Jab

ITEMS
Leather Armor, Spiked chain
====== Copy to Clipboard and Press the Import Button on the Summary Tab ======
```

Note, however, that because of the rogue's +1 to accuracy with daggers, the spiked chain offers only a rough increase of +1.03 damage on a given attack at level 1 and far less as levels increase due to the nature of scaling bonuses. Considering the difficulty of achieving combat advantage with a reach weapon, there is no normal benefit to wielding a spiked chain as a rogue.

Answer (score -1):

The chain technically counts as an exotic weapon so without the exotic weapon (spiked chain) feat it will probably keep giving you trouble.

Comment: False, actually. There's some interesting wording here and multiple interacting feats. It's really annoying.